# is there a limit on the number of times navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostion can be called?

Tags: geolocation, w3c

This is may not be a true programming question but deals with geolocation Api, hence hoping StackOverflow is the right place for this.

I'm calling the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition at every 3 seconds interval. After 10-15 tries the responses stop. So i'm wondering is there a limit on the number of calls being made, Or is it because i'm testing it with a desktop and hence instead of giving back the same response each time the API is waiting for a change of location.

Anyone has any experiences to share ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, there seems to be some sort of limit, but I am unable to find any definite information. I [asked about it](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1953347) in the MozillaZine forums. If I find out anything, I will post it here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of 1500 request per window defined in the Firefox source, but since it's quite high I suspect it's a bug: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/src/geolocation/nsGeolocation.cpp#96